# python opencv color

Tags: python, opencv

День добрый. Пожалуйста, объясните, где здесь что и как это использовать:

Есть код, берёт красный цвет. Где здесь BGR, где здесь HSV? Как, к примеру, сюда вставить желтый?

```
lower_range = np.array([169, 100, 100], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_range = np.array([189, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Обычно цвета читается в `RGB` формате, то есть `[169, 100, 100]` это 169 - красного, 100 зеленого и 100 синего. Желтый это приблизительно (https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) `255, 255, 0`. То есть чтобы получить желтый вам надо установить пиксель в `255, 255, 0`

Comment: пожалуйста прочтите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Скорее всего вы будете использовать данные границы в связке с OpenCv для выделения цвета. И скорее всего это границы в цветоой схеме HSV. Соответственно у вас 169 это тон, 100 насыщенность и 100 значение.

Comment: Границы для желтого значения будут [38, 100, 100] - нижняя граница и [50, 255, 255] верхняя граница для HSV. В HSV цвет определяется первым значением по шкале, которое можно определить по шкале: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/HueScale.svg

Comment: Но в opencv чаще встретишь bgr чем rgb